# How to find DeploymentId of an Azure VM deployed with Resource Manager?

Tags: azure, azure-diagnostics, azure-resource-manager

Azure Diagnostics Extension uses DeploymentId to store performance counter and other data in the storage tables.  However, when a VM is deployed thru Azure Resource Manager, finding out what this DeploymentId is, is not apparent.

How does one find this DeploymentId?  What API do I query?  I need to do this programmatically and I do not have access to the VM itself, can only to call the API.

Comment: look in to `resourceId` function https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/resource-group-template-functions/

Comment: Unfortunately, resourceId is a different entity all together.  DeploymentId is a Guid.  In "Classic" API world, it would get assigned to a deployment and exposed thru the API.  Everything would be "hanging off" a deployment.  In ARM world, I can't find it anywhere

Comment: Yes that's correct but you can use this with `reference` function to get to the property you need. Here's an example that I used and tested: `"APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY": "[reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Insights/components', concat(parameters('baseUriName'), '-MyAppName'))).InstrumentationKey]"` to get `.InstrumentationKey` property of AppInsights added within my ARM template

Comment: I see.  And do you know how to do this thru an outside application using the Resource Manager API after deployment?

Comment: Go to resources.azure.com and select the item you're interested in (web site for example), then select the category (lets say config/connectionstring) you'll see url to make get requests to the api (You have to add auth headers) in order to receive the data required

Comment: Rest API https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/azure/dn790568.aspx

Comment: I combed thru that API everywhere.  Found the InstrumentaitonKey in AppInsights. Unfortunately, DeploymentId is not to be found.  InstrumentationKey is not DeploymentId

Comment: Hi, do you have any specific requirement for the programmatic way to call the API? E.g. Azure PowerShell command, C# Azure management library

Comment: My requirement is to read data from diagnostic storage, and WADPerformanceCountersTable and I need deployment id for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no possibility to get the deploymentId of ARM VM via REST api:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/a228bb05-3a3f-488c-bd29-c2ea17ffc728/rest-api-to-get-vm-deployment-id-and-instance-id

Comment: We've found a pretty unreliable way of doing it, but it sort of sucks, hope MS fixes it